# How to use empty entries in CMake lists as arguments

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

When using a CMake list to specify multiple arguments to a function, empty arguments are not passed as arguments to the list. In some cases an empty string is needed as an argument. Is there a way to achieve this?

If I run this

```
set(CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT)

set(LIST_VAR
    "ONE"
    "TWO"
    ""
    "FOUR"
)
execute_process(
    COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo
        ${LIST_VAR}
)

execute_process(
    COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo
    "ONE"
    "TWO"
    ""
    "FOUR"
)
```

with

```sh
cmake -P test.cmake
```

I get:

```
'cmake' '-E' 'echo' 'ONE' 'TWO' 'FOUR'
ONE TWO FOUR
'cmake' '-E' 'echo' 'ONE' 'TWO' '' 'FOUR'
ONE TWO  FOUR
```

In the first variant the third, empty argument is swallowed, which is really annoying if there are cases, where an empty argument may be possible/needed and arguments are prepared as CMake lists.

In my application I need to call a script and not `cmake -E echo`, which expects empty arguments in certain situations.

Also, the empty entries are - of course - not put in literally as in this simplified example. Instead of `""` I have something like `"${MIGHT_BE_EMPTY}"`.

Is there a way to safely transport empty strings as list entries to function arguments?

If not, is there a good work-around for this problem?

E.g. transform unset variables to something like a space (`" "`) which might be equivalent to an empty argument for the called script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there are no lists in CMake, only strings. And there is a convention that some CMake commands understand: if there are unquoted `;` (semicolon) in the variable then it is a list, where each element of the list separated from another by `;`. And there is a rule which allows to create lists out of multiple strings separated by a whitespace.
So this command:

```
set(LIST_VAR
    "ONE"
    "TWO"
    ""
    "FOUR"
)
```

Creates a variable with the following content: `ONE;TWO;;FOUR` which is a list in the CMake book. Now there is [another rule](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#unquoted-argument) (reverse) which CMake uses when it expands unquoted variables:

> Each **non-empty element** is given to the command invocation as an
> argument.

So you can't use empty elements and have CMake lists propagate them across the script. You can use something non-empty like an empty element, though. For example, you could use the space character to mean the element is empty if it wouldn't mess with your other data:

```
set(EMPTY " ")
set(LIST_VAR
    "ONE"
    "TWO"
    "${EMPTY}"
    "FOUR"
    )
```

And if you can't modify the list with explicitly providing an `${EMPTY}` element you can add it to the existing list like this: `string(REPLACE ";;" ";${EMPTY};" LIST_VAR "${LIST_VAR}")`.

Finally, if you need to modify not a list but some particular, potentially empty variable then you can use the following:

```
if(MIGHT_BE_EMPTY STREQUAL "")
    set(MIGHT_BE_EMPTY "${EMPTY}")
endif()
```

I use the `EMPTY` variable because it is convenient, you can drop it and replace with whatever symbol you like—it won't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation! Unfortunately, I still do not know, what to do. I extended the question a bit. From your answer is only missing, how to get a space from an unset variable - preferably without any additional statements or intermediate variables.